# How do you access a 2-d HashTable in c# and append to an array?

Tags: c#, list, hashtable

Currently I have an array that is looks like this:

```
{
 "key" => 
    {"key1" => []},
 "key2" =>
    {"key3"=> []}
}
```

How do I append to the list that is Key1's value in c#? I am very new to this language!

Comment: This hashtable doesn't make sense.  You have two entries with the same key.

Comment: @Amy I was just using that as an example. I have edited it to make more sense.